# Can't reach Flask API running inside a docker container from another container

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I appreciate there have been lots of questions about Flask and Docker, and there even more blog posts about how to run a simple Flask API inside a docker container.

However, I'm having some troubles reaching a Flask API running inside a container for which I've set the host (`0.0.0.0`) and port (`5000`) from another container. The interesting thing is that if I spin up the container which hosts the API I can reach the API from my local browser.

What I'm trying to achieve is to first start a container which hosts a Postgres database, then one that hosts a Flask API (which uses Postgres for the backend, and finally spin up a container which run some unit tests against the database and API.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/app.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - todo_backend

  tests:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/tests.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - app
    networks:
      - todo_backend

  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    ports:
      - "5432"
    networks:
      - todo_backend


networks:
  todo_backend:
    driver: bridge
```

The Dockerfile for the API is:

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -P /usr/bin/ && \
  chmod +x /usr/bin/wait-for-it.sh

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]

CMD ["app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And here is the Dockerfile for the container that tries to reach the API...

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

COPY requirements.txt /todo/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -P /usr/bin/ && \
  chmod +x /usr/bin/wait-for-it.sh

WORKDIR /todo

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /todo

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]

CMD ["tests/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I run the tests, I first build the images with a `docker-compose build` and then run a `docker-compose up tests`

This is the error message I get:

```
tests_1  | E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /todo/api/v1.0/tasks (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc08e2489b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I've shorten it since it's way longer but the problems seems to be with the fact that the `tests` container doesn't seem to be able to reach the API at the address `http://0.0.0.0:5000`.

One thing I forgot to mention are the content of the `entrypoint.sh` files. They look like the one below:

```
set -e

bash wait-for-it.sh --timeout=5 db:5432

python app/app.py
```

As I mentioned above the issue is with reaching the API. I can run all the automated tests against the database without problems, but for some reason don't seem to be able to connect to the API.

This is a list of the containers and ports:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
1ea4d2b60d32        docker_app          "/bin/bash app/ent..."   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp    docker_app_1
09c21e7354ba        postgres:9.5        "docker-entrypoint..."   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:32816->5432/tcp   docker_db_1
```

Comment: Try to use the container name as the host: `http://docker_app_1:5000`

Comment: That's interesting. It works! Thank you @KlausD. Do you know why this is happening? Is it possible to make the tests pass pointing directly to host `0.0.0.0:5000` instead?

Comment: No, `0.0.0.0` is an invalid IP address but many implementations are handling it similar to localhost, so the connection would always go to container itself. The container name is resolved by Docker's built-in DNS service.